# What stats do cross-class cantrips use?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, feats, multi-classing

If you pick up a different class's cantrip through multi-classing, or Magic Initiate, etc, what stats do the cantrips use for determining if the attack hits? Does it matter if it's a melee or ranged spell attack or if it's a saving throw?

(E.g. a cleric picks up a wizard's *shocking grasp* and *poison spray*, does it use Int for determining hit/saving throw or Wis? Does it matter that *poison spray* is considered a Druid spell too?)

Answer (score 20):

**The feature with which you gain the cantrip will tell you which ability to use for casting the spell.**

For multicalssing, this is answered on page 164 of the PHB in the multiclassing rules for spellcasting:

> Each spell you know and prepare is associated with one of your classes, and **you use the spellcasting ability of that class when you cast the spell.**

It doesn't matter if a spell is *also* part of another classes spell list because you're not multi classing into *that* class.

As for the *Magic Initiate* feat, this is spelled out in the feat's description:

> Your spellcasting ability for these spells depends on the class you chose: Charisma for bard, sorcerer, or warlock: Wisdom for cleric or druid: or Intelligence for wizard.

If you gain a cantrip through a class feature such as the warlock's *Pact of the Tome* (which, mind you, had to be errata'd, so it will only show in later printings of the PHB) then it's not directly stated in the feature which ability to use but it does tell you that the cantrips are considered to be class (in this case warlock) spells for you which means you would use your original spellcasting ability for those cantrips.

Comment: You might also add that the Pact of the Tome is a bit different. Allowing all the cross-class cantrips chosen with that trait are treated as Warlock cantrips in this case.

Comment: Compare with Arcane Cleric (SCAG 125):  "For you, these cantrips count as cleric cantrips"